# In django where to specify application related settings

Tags: python, django

At present my application related variables like external server IP / default pattern etc.. These variables are specific to my application. It includes my external server username and password.

Now how can I have a single common place so that I can externalise this from my application.

The options which I thought are below:

- Have one conf.ini file and use configparser and read this during the start of the django app
- But I am not sure from where I should have method to read this so that it will be done in the startup.
- Other option is to save this in a py file itself and import this file in my modules

Please suggests me the good and standard approach for above issue.

Comment: why don't you put these variables in application's init.py file?

Comment: Even better, why not put them in settings.py?

Comment: ok will try in settings.py then what about passwords, can that be saved as the encrypted content itself then while getting decrypt it. Or any other good approach

Answer (score -1):

Save the important secret details in an ini file and place it in etc/project_name/my_settings.ini. Read these settings from settings.py. This way it will be secure. Can be read directly in the settings file itself

Or better way is to set them in bashrc, read the env vars from it.
Check this: [Setting envs](https://godjango.com/blog/working-with-environment-variables-in-python/)

Comment: How is using an ini file (clear text format) any more secure than directly putting those values in the django settings module ???

Comment: I did not say "clear text format"....Could use any encryption if following the first case...which I think will make it a little bit more secure than specifying in the django  settings